# Is it safe to re-create a SQLAlchemy object while server is running?

Tags: python, flask, thread-safety, flask-sqlalchemy, gunicorn

Our application uses flask + gunicorn. Now we want to make it able to reload db configuration while it is runing, which means it can switch to a new db without restart process. With the help of config center we can dispatch config at runtime, but how can I re-init the global varibale db?

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config.from_object(dynamic_config)
    db.init_app(app)
```

And assume at some time. We dispatch new config, how can db be init with new config? Or is it safe to just replace it with new SQLAlchemy() instance? Like do this:

```
from models import set_db # which will set global db to new instance
from app import app
def callback(odl, new):  
    new_db = SQLAlchemy()
    # re-construct config with old, and new
    # now app.config is updated
    new_db.init_app(app)
    set_db(new_db)
```

Is it ok to do this? As I'm concerned, it will cause something like thread safety and may destroy Transaction.

Help me with this, many thanks

Answer (score 0):

If i were you I would use [SQLALCHEMY_BINDS](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/binds/) config or different instances of db with different configs instead of changing configuration every time.
and I think it isn't good practice to change db structure using application(in case you are doing that)